# How to change volume of windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need to set the volume of windows to fixed 40% or 50% how?
Following only set it to previous value + new value not to a fixed value.

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm")

// to mute:
waveOutSetVolume(NULL, 0);

// full volume:
waveOutSetVolume(NULL, 0xFFFF);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [waveOutSetVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743874.aspx) explains, how the *dwVolume* parameter is interpreted:

> The low-order word contains the left-channel volume setting, and the high-order word contains the right-channel setting. [...]
>   If a device does not support both left and right volume control, the low-order word of dwVolume specifies the volume level, and the high-order word is ignored.

In other words, you have to construct a `DWORD` value for the volume, where both the high-order and low-order word are the same value (between 0 and 65535).

The following function returns an appropriate value based on an integer input that designates the percentage:

```
DWORD VolumeValue( const int percentage ) {
    // Clamp percentage value
    int p = min( 100, max( 0, percentage ) );
    // Calculate scaled value for one channel
    const WORD wVol = static_cast<WORD>( ::MulDiv( 65535, p, 100 ) );
    // Construct return value for both channels
    const DWORD retVal = ( ( wVol << 16 ) | wVol );
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23898336/ - for some reason its still not working? any idea.